# Response code not getting in android

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

How to get response code in ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar in android?

Comment: wow, what a art of asking so encapsulated question :)

Answer (score 2):

use Ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4 jar-with -dependencies.jar

Comment: @Roshni try to change the version of .jar file

Comment: Ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4 jar is deperectated??

Comment: yes..Iknow but it is working ..I am also using it just try once

Answer (score 0):

For information try this [Site](http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html) & [Site](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html) & [Site](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data). Here you ll get it, how to use ksoap2 android assembly with dependencies in android

Comment: Thanks @TechEnd but IS IT not any method in ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar ?